# excel extract word (GB) and number before it

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I have stuck I have excel sheet I need to extract GB and numbers from a string.
  Galaxy S10+ 8/128GB (Snapdragon 855) should be 128GB have no idea how to do it. cannot find any formulas which will use whilecard , any help?

I am using

> =IF((LEN(A3)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A3," ","")))<2,A3,LEFT(A3,FIND(" ",A3,FIND(" ",A3)+1)-1))
>   to extract phone name but stusk with a GB for it

[image]

Comment: just go to Data > Text to Columns and separate the cells using a space delimiter..this will break the text into a number of cells, and you can isolate any parts you need to split easier

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Frist we need to replace the `/` with a space then find the last space before GB and set that as the beginning of the mid formula:

```
=IFERROR(MID(LEFT(A2,FIND("GB",A2)+1),FIND("}}}",SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A2,FIND("GB",A2)+2),"/"," ")," ","}}}",LEN(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A2,FIND("GB",A2)+1),"/"," "))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A2,FIND("GB",A2)+1),"/"," ")," ",""))))+1,LEN(A2)),"")
```

[image]

Comment: do you know if there is join in excel?

Comment: Depends on which version you are using.

Comment: I am using 2013

Comment: Then no, not without vba.

Answer (score 4):

In Excel 2013, which has the `FILTERXML` function, you can use:

```
=IFERROR(FILTERXML("<t><s>" &SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/"," ")," ","</s><s>") & "</s></t>","//s[contains(.,'GB')]"),"")
```

[image]

- Using the spaces (and replacing the `/` with a space), we create an XML where each node is defined by the space separation.
- We then use an `Xpath` to return the node that contains GB

Answer (score 1):

If the string meets the following criteria:

- The maximum number of numeric characters before GB is no longer than **4**, eg. there will be no string showing 12345GB; and
- There will always be either `/` or `" "`(space) before the numeric value in front of GB, eg. `/128GB` or `32GB` (with a space in front of 32)

you can use the following formula to find the desired text out of the string.

```
=IFERROR(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(MID(A1,FIND("GB",A1)-5,7)," ","/"),LEN(SUBSTITUTE(MID(A1,FIND("GB",A1)-5,7)," ","/"))-FIND("/",SUBSTITUTE(MID(A1,FIND("GB",A1)-5,7)," ","/"))),"")
```

The logic is to

1. use **MID** to extract **5 characters in front of GB** plus "GB" (hence **7 characters in total**) from the string,
2. **SUBSTITUTE** " " (space) with `/` within the 7 characters from last step,
3. **FIND** the position of `/` within the 7 characters,
4. use **RIGHT** function to extract all characters on the right hand side of `/`,
5. use **IFERROR** to show "" (blank cell) if there is no GB in the string.

The formula could be shorter and easier to be interpreted if you use a helper column to store the text string from Step 1.

Cheers :)